# Where and how can I patent a web improvement or idea?

Tags: web

I have one idea that could improve web interfaces and functionality of web sites.

Where and how could I patent that idea?

Answer (score 2):

In short, Patent for a method or a product is issued by patent office of a country for that country. You have to prepare documents and drawings to describe your invention and claims in a particular format and should be filed along with designated forms and fees of the patent office to the patent office electronically or in person.

The following can be your guidelines.

i. Never disclose your invention to any person or organization without non-disclosure agreement and to public in any form of communication, demonstration or exhibition.

ii. If you are employee or with any university, institution and organisation, your employer or institution may be your assignee and take responsibility of getting patent for your invention.

iii. If  (ii) is not applicable or you have no objection in writing from them, than if you can afford, engage a legal professional or firm for assessing patentability and if advised to process your patent application proceed. It is always advisable but costly proposition.

iii. If you can not afford cost of attorney, and your country allows filing as pro se inventor i.e. by inventor himself/herself without engaging a patent attorney or agent, take pain to study patent applications in the field at uspto, epo and google on line. Manuals of patent office of your country will also be helpful.

iv. Lots of 'how to file patent in ----- (country name)' will enlighten you. Spare some time for browsing.

Good luck.

Comment: All good advice, but it doesn’t answer the question of whether his web interface idea is patentable. Not surprising since without knowing more about the idea we can’t provide that opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no way we can provide a useful opinion on patentability of your idea. First, the ability to obtain software related patents varies by jurisdiction. Second, without a detailed knowledge of your idea we can't judge whether or not it is obvious, abstract or whether there is prior art. **You can't provide this information publicly** without jeopardizing your potential patentability.

Bottom line is that you should consider obtaining the advice of a patent attorney, ideally one with experience in software related patents.